# MongoDb : Issue using $divide and $gte

Tags: c#, mongodb, filter

I am new to MongoDb. I have problem When i using `$divide` and `$gte` below code don't give me error. But it's filter is not working.

**Code :**

```
var filter1 = new BsonDocument()
              { 
                {"expr",
                        new BsonDocument(){
                        {
                            "$gte", new BsonArray{
                                new BsonDocument{
                                {
                                    "$divide", new BsonArray{"$nA", "$wT"}
                                },
                            },
                            sPacketMSItem.FromDPC.Value
                        }
                      }
                    }
                   }
                 };
```

If anyone reuquire more information than tell me.

**Exception :**

> {MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command find failed: unknown
>   top level operator: $expr.    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId
>   connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection
>   connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.ServerChannel.ExecuteProtocolAsync[TResult](IWireProtocol`1
>   protocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CommandOperationBase`1.ExecuteProtocolAsync(IChannelSource
>   channelSource, ICoreSessionHandle session, ReadPreference
>   readPreference, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.ReadCommandOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(IReadBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindCommandOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(IReadBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(IReadBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteReadOperationAsync[TResult](IReadBinding
>   binding, IReadOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteReadOperationAsync[TResult](IClientSessionHandle
>   session, IReadOperation`1 operation, ReadPreference readPreference,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2
>   funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToListAsync[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1
>   source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Biz.DAL.MongoRepositoriesCustom.SalesCRMRepository.MarketSheet.MarketSheetRepository.SearchBySearchPacketMSItemAsync(SearchPacketMSItem
>   sPacketMSItem) in
>   /Users/lalitdevani/Documents/AasthaSalesWebApi/Aastha/_git/Sales.WebApi/Biz.DAL/MongoRepositoriesCustom/SalesCRMRepository/MarketSheet/MarketSheetRepository.cs:line
>   142}

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) is an Evaluation Query Operator so it should be prefixed with dollar sign, try:

```
var filter1 = new BsonDocument()
            { 
                {"$expr",
                        new BsonDocument(){
                        {
                            "$gte", new BsonArray{
                                new BsonDocument{
                                {
                                    "$divide", new BsonArray{"$nA", "$wT"}
                                },
                            },
                            sPacketMSItem.FromDPC.Value
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
            };
```

EDIT: `$expr` is available in MongoDB 3.6 or higher, as a fallback you can use [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/), try:

```
var redact = new BsonDocument()
        {
        {"$redact",
                new BsonDocument
                {
                    {
                        "$cond", new BsonDocument(){
                        {
                            "if", new BsonDocument()
                            {
                                { "$gte", new BsonArray
                                    {
                                        new BsonDocument{
                                        {
                                            "$divide", new BsonArray{"$nA", "$wT"}
                                        },
                                    },
                                    sPacketMSItem.FromDPC.Value
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {  "then", "$$KEEP"  },
                        {  "else", "$$PRUNE" }
                    }
                    }
                }
        }
    };

var result = Col.Aggregate()
                .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(redact).ToList();
```

Comment: `$expr` was introduced in MongoDB version 3.6, what version do you use ?

Comment: `MongoDB.Driver` version is `2.6.1` Nuget package.

Comment: I mean MongoDB as database, not the driver (db.version() in Mongo shell to check)

Comment: MongoDB version is 3.4.4

Comment: @Ironman that explains why it throws an exception. Are you able to upgrade or you need a workaround ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185782/discussion-between-ironman-and-mickl).